# Correct Strategy for Element to be not present in DOM

Tags: protractor, cucumber, pom, typescript

I have scratching my heads around this problem for two days. I have a test where I need to check if a spinner is not visible to the user. This is the first test of a series of tests, and until the spinner is not visible, the page elements are not displayed to the user.

I have been trying to implement a wait in order to wait for the element to be invisible , but my tests seem to fail and the tests exit with a success code, however I can still see the spinner being available on the page.

I have even tried the dirty `browser.sleep()` method, but my tests doesn't even wait for the sleep duration that I have given.

I have this given block of HTML

```
<div class ="loadingContent">
<div class="always-loader">...</div>
<div class ="first-time-loader">
    <div>
    <div class ="text> Preparing the App just for you</div>
    <img src ="images/d92f6c4a.horizontal_loader.gif">
    </div>
</div>
```

My test checks that `img` is not present in the DOM or is not displayed. I have a function that waits for this purpose

### Try 1

```
  public waitForSpinnerDisappear(){
  browser.sleep(100000);
    let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; 
    const condition = until.elementIsNotVisible($('[src="images/d92f6c4a.horizontal_loader.gif"]'));
    return browser.wait(condition,500000);

 }
```

### Try2

```
  let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
```

`browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf($('[src="images/d92f6c4a.horizontal_loader.gif"]')),500000);`

### Try3

```
public waitForSpinnerDisappear(){
browser.wait(function(){
  return $('[src="images/d92f6c4a.horizontal_loader.gif"]').isDisplayed()
  .then(function(result){
    return !result;
  });
  },500000);

 }
```

All these conditions doesn't wait for the spinner to disappear from the page and my tests exit with a success code

```
  1 scenario (1 passed)
  2 steps (2 passed)
  0m00.005s


[12:04:20] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:04:20] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
Done in 19.54s.
```

I can't provide the URL for the application since it's an internal application but I can give the gist for the code in case it's needed. My question here is what do I need to do more in order for the web page to load for the spinner to be loaded.

I have gone through the following SO post's for reference but the solutions given here doesn't work

- [Post 1](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27073/wait-for-element-change-not-present-webdriver-javascript-jest)
- [Post 2](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22863/selenium-how-to-wait-for-javascript-fadeout-visibility-and-clickable-dont-wor/29011#29011)
- [Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811579/how-to-handle-spinners-using-protractor)

Edit : After some more debugging, I believe that this is something related to Cucumber. I had the same code without Cucumber and my tests wait for the loader to disappear.

Can someone point me in the direction where the issue might be ?

Comment: That `d92f6c4a` part in the selector looks auto-generated to me - are you sure `[src="images/d92f6c4a.horizontal_loader.gif"]` matches the spinner element during your test run? What if you change the locator to `.first-time-loader img[src*=loader]`? Thanks.

Comment: Well the`d92f6c4a` part is not auto-generated. I used the locator as mentioned but it didn't work out.

Comment: Does the spinner remain in the DOM after it becomes invisible? One problem I have run into with waiting for an element to not exist is that sometimes the check occurs before it is initially loaded in the DOM in the first place. In those scenarios, when I **know** the element should appear at least for an instant, I will first wait for the element to exist **then** wait for it to not exist. Of course this tidbit isn't helpful if the problem is indeed caused by Cucumber.

Comment: @VanderLinden the spinner doesn't remain in the DOM post becoming invisible. Although I have got a working solution, I highly doubt  that is is brittle and prone to failure. Please see the answer.

Comment: @demouser123 Yes It is ajax/jquery loader. It appears only in specific conditions. Now identify the conditions like 1. Scroll Down 2. Click on some element 3. Hover on some element etc. Then first perform that event and try to fetch loader. Now for the stopping it. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895515/what-does-protractor-browser-wait-return-if-the-condition-never-becomes-true

Comment: @Sagar007 not it doesn't appear in specific conditions - it loads on page load every time. Also I already tried the solution in the link that you've specified and it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe the loader is not yet there when you check for it. A "wait for element visible", followed by a "wait for element not visible" could help in that case.

Comment: @demouser123 I am not sure, But can you put some wait or sleep or pause execution time ?

Comment: @Sagar007 Already mentioned that sleep is not doing the job.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for an element on the page that you know is only visible once the spinner is gone? So using `visibilityOf(WebElement element)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long hard fought battle, I was able to overcome this using opposite of what K-8 had suggested.

Instead of checking if an element is visible on the viewport, I checked the negative of that, which is if element is not visible on the viewport.

So, I did this

```
public waitForSpinnerDisappear(){    
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.not(EC.visibilityOf($(element_locator))));
}
```

In my tests, I am using `async/await` so, I paired my test in a Step Def like this

```
   Given(/^User waits for some time for spinner to disappear$/, async ()=>{

   await pageobject.waitForSpinnerDisappear();
 });
```

It's worth noting that I was able to overcome this using `visibilityOf` which is defined by Protractor API as

> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. This is the opposite of 'invisibilityOf'.

However, if I use `invisibilityOf` (as in Try 2), the test fails.

I would welcome suggestions as to how I can improve this even further.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf) ?

Which is better suited in this scenario as you need to wait until a certain element is no longer attached to the DOM.

[ProtractorExpectedConditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf)